# Fabric js sending image from canvas

Tags: fabricjs

I have buquet creator in canvas  and  I want to make  save button where canvas is converted to png file. And after I fill the form It should send a email to admin with png attached. 
Is it posible to do this conversion with fabric js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acheive this using [toDataURL()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toDataURL).

```
canvas.toDataURL({
  format:'png'
});
```

Comment: I didnt know that method before . From now I'm gonna handle this .Thanks a lot !